# How to use WHERE NOT clause in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a table like:

```
  id      Model        Color
------  --------     ----------
1        Ford           yellow
2        Ford           green
3        Ford           red
4        Ford           yellow
5        Subaru         yellow
6        Fiat            red
```

I need to make a query, which returns me every car's color in list, except for fiat car. How to implement this query using firebase query standards?

Comment: There is not equivalent of a `WHERE NOT` operation in Firebase. You'll either have to exclude the Fiat's client-side or come up with a data structure that allows the server-side filtering (i.e. have a list of colors-of-cars-that-are-not-fiats).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen am I right in saying [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/6530134) is related and could help? (it was ironically answered by you!)

Comment: It's related, but not the same. The one you link is about querying for multiple values, which sometimes is possible. But they're all related in that you'll need to model your data to allow the queries you need for your app.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Is it a good practice to fetch data from firebase database and save it in  the array and then filter accordingly?

Comment: It's one common approach. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752402/firebase-database-not-equal-request-alternative-solution-for-ios, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223/is-it-possible-query-data-that-are-not-equal-to-the-specified-condition/28619795#28619795, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833790/what-is-the-best-method-to-exclude-data-and-query-parts-of-data-in-a-swift-fireb/35833954#35833954 and probably a few more.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752402/firebase-database-not-equal-request-alternative-solution-for-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752402/firebase-database-not-equal-request-alternative-solution-for-ios)  how to apply this concept in case of android?

Comment: The APIs between languages are fairly similar, so I recommend you give it a try ([documentation on list handling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)). If you have a specific part where you get stuck, post the code where you got stuck.