# How to query where child does not exists in Firebase?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say that we have simple data structure:

```
"games": {
     "{gameId}" {
          "title": "Chess",
          "playedBy" : {
               "{userId}" : true,
               "{userId}" : true
           }
     }
}
```

There are just games and every game has data about users who played in this game. Now I want to get all games where specified user (let's say his id is `"1234567"`) didn't play. I have to query games where `"playedBy"` does not contain `"1234567"`.

How can I achieve that with Firebase?

Every language where Firebase works will be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know there is no support for "not equals" operator in Firebase for now.

Comment: Please check with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37752402/firebase-database-not-equal-request-alternative-solution-for-ios

Comment: Firebase can only query for values that are present. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582223/is-it-possible-query-data-that-are-not-equal-to-the-specified-condition

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

1. Iterate trough all the games
2. Check if each game contains the user id
3. If not , add the game to list of games

   ```
   mGamesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.child("playedBy").hasChild(userId)) {
                gamesList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Game.class));
            }
       }
       ...
   ```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Such disappointing solution...